# AngularJS templates with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

I am writing an AngularJS directive that uses a `templateURL` i.e.

```
m.directive('mySavingIndicator', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/views/templates/savingindicator.html'
    };
});
```

I have created a plain old .html file within the `views/templates` directory but everytime I run this code MVC throws a null reference exception like its trying to find a controller for it (which doesnt exist).  How do I stop MVC trying to treat this as a `cshtml` file, or how do I make it treat it as a `cshtml` file but not require a controller? It seems wasteful writing a controller just for these small templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC normally prevents any content files from being served from the Views folder (the Views folder is special).

However, you can change this by tweaking your web.config.

Change this:

```
<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"    type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

To this:

```
<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

Example:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="JavaScriptHandler" path="*.js" verb="*"
     preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />      
  <add name="HtmlScriptHandler" path="*.html" verb="*"
     preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```

That way, only cshtml files are blocked from being served directly (html files are left alone).

Comment: This looks promising! I dont have this line yet, what section would it be in?

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, I get errors about `name` being invalid and `preCondition`. If I remove these nothing works.  I might, however, move my templates into another folder to work around this. Thanks

Comment: If I move the file outside of `views`, either to the root MVC folder or `Scripts` I can access the file directly but everytime Angular tries to load it I get `400 bad request`.  Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to add `IgnoreRoute` in `RouteConfig`.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("views/templates/savingindicator.html");
```

Comment: Can I make it ignore that entire folder?